# Send e-mail to Exchange server via authentication NTLM

Tags: php, email, ntlm-authentication

**UPDATE: only one valid solution is Symphony mailer
https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html**

PHPMailer has no support of NTLM authentication.

And I finally could not find any alternative that should use SMTP protocol and user authentication via NTLM.

Do you know anybody how to solve sending e-mail to Exchange 2016 servet using SMTP proctocol that requires user login by command "AUTH NTLM"

Comment: does this help https://cheesefather.com/2017/06/phpmailer-ntlm-ms-exchange-smtp-authentication/ ?